# curl command giving error in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, curl, chef-infra

I am trying to use the `curl` command on my Linux host but it gives me error:

command is:

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

The error that I am getting:

```
[root@abc ~]# curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Comment: I guess ur net connection is lost, since it's working perfectly from my terminal.

Comment: It works for me too in some host but not in other.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you tell us more about your environement:

Do you need a proxy to surf ? (curl is still http protocol)

Does www.opscode.com  resolve (with something like `dig www.opscode.com`)

According to the error it sounds more a firewalling/network configuration problem than something else.

So check:

1. Is the gateway corretly configured
2. If you need a proxy, are the http_proxy and https_proxy env vars set ?
3. If there's firewalling somewhere, does it allow your machine to access port 443 on the internet

Comment: Let me know what all information you are asking for.? and what all I need to check

Comment: Seriously ? Is it not clear enought ? You machine obvisouly resolve www.opscode.com but can't get the install.sh file, so you have something preventing communication between your box and the website... At least make an effort to answer if you need a proxy or not or if you don't even know if you need one or not